# Change border Brush WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

Hi there i am new to WPF.I have applied round corner text box by using

```
<Window.Resources>
```

saw on some website do not know if it is best.

Now i may have 4 text boxes all having round corners
I have selected a border brush color and want that it should change when ever the some particular textbox has focus.so i added event

```
private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxCpanelUserName.BorderBrush = Brushes.OrangeRed;           
        }
```

but no effect.I checked when text box has focus the event fires but never changes the value of border brush.

Following is my XMAL

```
<Window x:Class="AutomatingSomething.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"       
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" Name="MainContainer" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WPFControls.Clocks;assembly=WPFControls" xmlns:common="clr-namespace:WPF.Common">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxBaseControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="#FF3BB5C8"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="7">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>                
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                <Trigger Property="Width" Value="Auto">
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Height" Value="Auto">
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                </Trigger>

            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Name="MasterGrid">        
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF484848" Offset="0.075" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8A8A8A" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="0" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="902,12,0,0" Name="border1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88">
            <my:RetroClock Name="retroClock1" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Normal" />
        </Border>
        <Button Content="Button" Name="button1" Margin="12,25,907,608" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Grid common:VisibilityAnimation.AnimationType="Fade" Height="524" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="101,25,0,0" Name="CpanelSettings" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="665">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFD4D4D4" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF797979" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Label Content="Cpanel Settings" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="289,6,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="26" FontFamily="Tekton Pro" FontStretch="Condensed" Width="147">
                <Label.Foreground>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFB4AFAF" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Label.Foreground>
            </Label>
            <TextBox Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="132,50,0,0" Name="textBoxCpanelUserName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="187" FontFamily="Tekton Pro" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="2" Template="{StaticResource TextBoxBaseControlTemplate}" FontSize="15" BorderBrush="#FF3BB5C8" GotFocus="textBox1_GotFocus" />
            <Label Content="Cpanel Settings" FontFamily="Tekton Pro" FontSize="20" FontStretch="Condensed" FontWeight="Bold" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,46,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
                <Label.Foreground>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFB4AFAF" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Label.Foreground>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have one more question that if i draw new textbox and try to make its corner round by the drawn template then if i change the color on one textbox on focus all get updated?(i donot want that)

---

**I am extremely sorry if i have said any non-technical thing or said the things wrong.Its because i am totaly new to wpf**

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add following Trigger to ControlTemplate.Triggers

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="Red"/>
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you forgot to bind Bd's BorderBrush in TextBoxBaseControlTemplate as you made it for Background.

Template should look like the following:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxBaseControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF3BB5C8"/>
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="7">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>                
     </Border>
...
```

Comment: actully i copied frome someone's website.and yes i think it is for background but when i change the border brush here it gets changed

Comment: About your second question. Template works as a factory for visual tree for each element. That means that each TextBox will have it's own representation of template and therefore if you change color of one TextBox this will have no effect on another TextBox (because they share only factory, but not actual elements).